# Selenium css and xpath selector not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm trying to use selenium's css selector to click a login buttton at dsound.audio.  it's the button on the top right.  I've tried using selenium's default selector as well as xpath and css, but nothing will work.  The css method I'm using is supposed to find a tag by its title attribute but this is the error I'm getting:

selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified

here's my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://dsound.audio")

driver.maximize_window()

login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[title=Login with your Steem account]")

login.click()
```

And here's xpath code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://dsound.audio")

driver.maximize_window()

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@title = 'Login with your Steem account']")

login.click()
```

The error with that is simply that the element isn't visible even though it is.

Comment: When I go to that page, I first see a loading spinner. Did you wait for that to stop?

Comment: I set an implicit wait for at least 10 seconds.

Comment: I set the wait for 60 seconds but I'm still getting the element not visible error for my xpath selector.

Comment: Implicit wait is not what you want! IMHO: implicit wait should be completely removed from Selenium as it accomplishes nothing useful. Read up on explicit waits.

Comment: I tried explicit wait but it's still giving me the same error for my xpath selector.

Comment: Post a [mcve], or it didn't happen.

Comment: I already did.  It's minimal complete and verifiable.  I included the url of the website I'm using and the code.

Comment: Am I right saying the first example with css_selector gives an invalid selector because you miss some quotes ? You can wrap the value of title in single ' quotes